# Are both of these sentences correctly ordered?

Tags: word-order, comparison

Are both of these sentences correctly ordered?

> The Dutch are better at speaking English than the Danish.
>
> The Dutch are better than the Danish at speaking English.

Does the order matter here?

Comment: No it doesn't. But one might become preferable if you were to extend the sentence. eg. It would be better to write: The Dutch are better than the Danish at speaking English, French and German because of their superior education system.

Comment: And you will hear native speakers sometimes adding **are**:  *The Dutch are better at speaking English than the Danish are.* and *The Dutch are better than the Danish are at speaking English*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, no. They are equivalent.

However, the first one sounds more fluid and natural imo. Also, there may be slightly different implications. In the first sentence, I think of Dutch people speaking English, in the second sentence more attention is on the contrast between the Dutch and the Danish.

In this particular case, there is very little difference between these sentences though.